# Multipart Form Errors with Lagom

Tags: scala, playframework, multipartform-data, lagom

Most of our Lagom entrypoints don't use multipart form requests, but one does. Since Lagom doesn't currently support multipart requests natively, the general suggestion I have seen is to call the underlying Play API, using the PlayServiceCall mechanism.

We have done that, and it works--most of the time. But we experience intermittent errors, especially when submitting large files. These are always cases of `java.util.zip.ZipException` (of various kinds), looking as if not an entire file has been received for processing.

Here's how the entrypoint looks in the code; in particular, the Play wrapping mechanism:

```
def upload = PlayServiceCall[NotUsed, UUID] {
  wrapCall => Action.async(multipartFormData) {
    request => wrapCall(ServiceCall { _ =>
      val upload = request.body.file("upload")
      val input = new FileInputStream(upload.get.ref.file)
      val filename = upload.get.filename
      // ...
      // other code to actually process the file
      // ...
    })(request).run
  }
}
```

Here are just two examples of exceptions we're seeing:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:214)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
  etc.

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:214)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
  etc.
```

We use Lagom 1.3.8, in Scala. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the new service gateway based on Akka HTTP.

You can enable this by adding the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
lagomServiceGatewayImpl in ThisBuild := "akka-http"
```

The new service gateway is still disabled by default in Lagom 1.3.8, but Lagom users that have experienced this problem have reported that it is resolved by enabling the `akka-http` gateway. This will become the default implementation in Lagom 1.4.0.